# H4 does not change the inner

Tags: javascript, windows, arrow-functions

I'm learning JS and making a program that change the inner of a `<h4>` changing it for the value of a input, but when I press the button that changes the inner the `<h4>` is empty.

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const h4 = document.getElementById('h4');
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    button.onclick = () => h4.innerHTML = input;
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code executed once, when the pages loads. So, that time the
let input = document.getElementById('input').value; have no value.
On clicks that "no value" copied in h4.innerHTML

Change button.onclick = () => h4.innerHTML = input;
to this: button.onclick = () => h4.innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;
This way the h4.innerHTML takes the value of   document.getElementById('input')  when the click happens.
You dont need the: let input = document.getElementById('input').value;

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const h4 = document.getElementById('h4');
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.on('click', () => { h4.innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;}); 
});
```